# android layout with center text and two views around

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have layout to show some header like this:

[image]

but when centered text is long, then view is not good.
This is what happens:
[image]

How to get something like this:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<View
    android:background="#0000CC"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<View
    android:background="#CC0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Thanks for the help

UPD: The closest **solution**:

I use LinearLayout + layout_width="0dp" + layout_weight=0.15/0.7/0.15 for items.

Comment: Very simple.. Give padding both sides.

Comment: padding was not help.

Comment: Change 

    `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` 

 to 

    `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` 

in your `<View  ...` tag 
and remove 

    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

from `<TextView ... ` tag.And don't forget to clear your project.

Comment: layout_gravity also not solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Get answer from this link

> [Justify text in an Android app using a WebView but presenting a TextView-like interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922861/how-to-justify-text-on-a-textview-made-easy-android)

It was getting on my nerves, I admit it. I like the `TextViews` to look like `TextViews` in the code, and even if I'm using a `WebView` as the means of achieving the text-align:justified formatting, I don't want to look at it that way.

I created a custom view (ugly, probably bad) that implements the methods that I commonly use from the `TextView` and modifies the content of the WebView in order to reflect those changes. 
Wether it's useful for someone else or a potential hazard I really don't know, for me it works, I've used it in several projects and haven't run into any issues. The only minor inconvenience is that I assume it as a bigger toll memory-wise but nothing to worry about if it's just one or two (correct me if I'm wrong).

The result is the following:

[image]

And the code for setting it programmatically is as simple as this:

```
 JustifiedTextView J = new JustifiedTextView();
                   J.setText("insert your text here");
```

Of course it'd be stupid to leave it like that so I also added the methods for changing the font-size and the font-color which are basically all I use TextViews for. Meaning I can do something like this:

```
 JustifiedTextView J = new JustifiedTextView();
                   J.setText("insert your text here");
                   J.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                   J.setTextSize(30);
```

And obtain the following result (images are cropped):

[image]

**But, this is not to show us how it looks, it's to share how you've done it!**

I know, I know.
Here's the full code. It also addresses Problems when setting transparent background and loading UTF-8 strings into the view. See the comments in reloadData() for details.

```
public class JustifiedTextView extends WebView{
    private String core      = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;color:rgba(%s);font-size:%dpx;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;'>%s</body></html>";
    private String textColor = "0,0,0,255";
    private String text      = "";
    private int textSize     = 12;
    private int backgroundColor=Color.TRANSPARENT;

    public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
    }

    public void setText(String s){
        this.text = s;
        reloadData();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void reloadData(){

        // loadData(...) has a bug showing utf-8 correctly. That's why we need to set it first.
        this.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        this.loadData(String.format(core,textColor,textSize,text), "text/html","utf-8");

        // set WebView's background color *after* data was loaded.
        super.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

        // Hardware rendering breaks background color to work as expected.
        // Need to use software renderer in that case.
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            this.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int hex){
        String h = Integer.toHexString(hex);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(0, 2),16);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(2, 4),16);
        int g = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(4, 6),16);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(6, 8),16);
        textColor = String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d", r, g, b, a); 
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int hex){
        backgroundColor = hex;
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int textSize){
        this.textSize = textSize;
        reloadData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinearLayout like this. Hope it will help you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<View
    android:background="#0000CC"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="The quick "
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<View
    android:background="#CC0000"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this