# text should fill whole line of the textview

Tags: android, textview

I am just starting android may be this question is already on SO. But I am not getting what to search for.

Like I have TextView in which I have to show some Large text right not i am getting this in UI.

[image]

But what I have to create is :-

[image]

You can see that the If word is long and not able fit in the end then it should break in two lines. But text alignment in the right should be there.

Do anybody know how can I achieve this ? any help and pointers are appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: @bgplaya can you explain what you want to say ?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I put wrong link in there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android/560958#560958 Try this answer - i'm using that widget for a long time. Put words in separate text views and add them to this layout - it will justify 'em automatically. Or just use third party lib for that.

Comment: Thanks @bgplaya Actually I am using Xamarin so It is difficult for me to go for new one now. But the ans below is fine. I have successfully ported the code.It is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to port it to c# from the following code. This method is without using `WebView`. As the WebView Implementation is quite slow i can't afford that.

Below is the full class of Justified TextView. `This is working great` This is from [**https://github.com/merterhk/JustifiedTextView**](https://github.com/merterhk/JustifiedTextView)

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.view.View;

public class JustifiedTextView extends View {
        String text;
        ArrayList<Line> linesCollection = new ArrayList<Line>();
        TextPaint textPaint;
        Typeface font;
        int textColor;
        float textSize = 42f, lineHeight = 57f, wordSpacing = 15f, lineSpacing = 15f;
        float onBirim, w, h;
        float leftPadding, rightPadding;

        public JustifiedTextView(Context context, String text) {
                super(context);
                this.text = text;
                init();
        }

        private void init() {
                textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                textColor = Color.BLACK;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

                if (font != null) {
                        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Trykker-Regular.ttf");
                        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
                }
                textPaint.setColor(textColor);

                int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
                w = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
                h = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

                onBirim = 0.009259259f * w;
                lineHeight = textSize + lineSpacing;
                leftPadding = 3 * onBirim + getPaddingLeft();
                rightPadding = 3 * onBirim + getPaddingRight();

                textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

                wordSpacing = 15f;
                Line lineBuffer = new Line();
                this.linesCollection.clear();
                String[] lines = text.split("\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                        String[] words = line.split(" ");
                        lineBuffer = new Line();
                        float lineWidth = leftPadding + rightPadding;
                        float totalWordWidth = 0;
                        for (String word : words) {
                                float ww = textPaint.measureText(word) + wordSpacing;
                                if (lineWidth + ww + (lineBuffer.getWords().size() * wordSpacing) > w) {// is
                                        lineBuffer.addWord(word);
                                        totalWordWidth += textPaint.measureText(word);
                                        lineBuffer.setSpacing((w - totalWordWidth - leftPadding - rightPadding) / (lineBuffer.getWords().size() - 1));
                                        this.linesCollection.add(lineBuffer);
                                        lineBuffer = new Line();
                                        totalWordWidth = 0;
                                        lineWidth = leftPadding + rightPadding;
                                } else {
                                        lineBuffer.setSpacing(wordSpacing);
                                        lineBuffer.addWord(word);
                                        totalWordWidth += textPaint.measureText(word);
                                        lineWidth += ww;
                                }
                        }
                        this.linesCollection.add(lineBuffer);
                }
                setMeasuredDimension((int) w, (int) ((this.linesCollection.size() + 1) * lineHeight + (10 * onBirim)));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawLine(0f, 10f, getMeasuredWidth(), 10f, textPaint);
                float x, y = lineHeight + onBirim;
                for (Line line : linesCollection) {
                        x = leftPadding;
                        for (String s : line.getWords()) {
                                canvas.drawText(s, x, y, textPaint);
                                x += textPaint.measureText(s) + line.spacing;
                        }
                        y += lineHeight;
                }
        }

        public String getText() {
                return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
        }

        public Typeface getFont() {
                return font;
        }

        public void setFont(Typeface font) {
                this.font = font;
        }

        public float getLineHeight() {
                return lineHeight;
        }

        public void setLineHeight(float lineHeight) {
                this.lineHeight = lineHeight;
        }

        public float getLeftPadding() {
                return leftPadding;
        }

        public void setLeftPadding(float leftPadding) {
                this.leftPadding = leftPadding;
        }

        public float getRightPadding() {
                return rightPadding;
        }

        public void setRightPadding(float rightPadding) {
                this.rightPadding = rightPadding;
        }

        public void setWordSpacing(float wordSpacing) {
                this.wordSpacing = wordSpacing;
        }

        public float getWordSpacing() {
                return wordSpacing;
        }

        public float getLineSpacing() {
                return lineSpacing;
        }

        public void setLineSpacing(float lineSpacing) {
                this.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        }

        class Line {
                ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
                float spacing = 15f;

                public Line() {
                }

                public Line(ArrayList<String> words, float spacing) {
                        this.words = words;
                        this.spacing = spacing;
                }

                public void setSpacing(float spacing) {
                        this.spacing = spacing;
                }

                public float getSpacing() {
                        return spacing;
                }

                public void addWord(String s) {
                        words.add(s);
                }

                public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
                        return words;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

justify alignment in TextView is what you are looking for and it's not implemented. However, you can try something like this in your layout file:

`android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center"`

If this does not suits you, then you can try using **[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)** instead of textview. [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922861/justify-text-in-an-android-app-using-a-webview-but-presenting-a-textview-like-in) of a helpfull alingment in webview