# How can I justify a textview in Android without using a webview?

Tags: android, textview

I need to justify the text inside a text view, I need to use a text view (not a webview) because my text is expandable,need your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-show-html-string-in-android-textview-webview

Comment: hope this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922861/justify-text-in-an-android-app-using-a-webview-but-presenting-a-textview-like-in

Answer (score 1):

Android text view does not support text Justification yet.

Answer (score 0):

Justify support for TextViews will come with Android O and new Support libraries.