# How to justify webView text in android

Tags: android, webview

I want use `webView` in my application and I should set **justify** texts into of `webview`.

I write below code for set image size, but how can I add **justify** text into this code :

```
private String getHtmlData(String bodyHTML) {
    String head = "<head><style>img{max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto;}</style></head>";
    return "<html>" + head + "<body>" + bodyHTML + "</body></html>";
}
```

set html to webview :

```
            content_newsWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(response.body().getData().getDescription())
                    , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

How can I add justify text into `webView`?

Comment: AFAIK, use `text-align: justify`. This has little to do with Android and `WebView` and everything to do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you my friend, but I am amateur. can you send to me full code with my above codes? please

Comment: As @CommonsWare sir suggest, you can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922861/2949612 . It may helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as in html

```
return "<html>" + head + "<body style='text-align: justify;'>" + bodyHTML + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: I am amateur, can you send to me full code with my above codes? please